# Bode Plot method

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot

I understand how to get curve 1,2,3 and 4. the last step is "The overall curve is shifted vertically by an amount determined by the multiplicative constant of the transfer function''. as you can see the multiplicative constant is 20dB but what I don't get is how does this result in curve 5? in other words how they got curve 5 from shifting everything by 20dB so that the gain is 60dB? can anyone explain this for me please?

[image]

Comment: the bode bode is correct, but I don't understand how they got curve 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curve 1 rises from a zero and ramps up to intersect the 100 rad/sec point at 40 dB. At this point curve 2 cancels the rise to a flat line remaining at 40 dB. Curve 3 comes along at 100,000 rad/sec and starts declining the "flat" to a 20dB/decade slope downwards.

Curve 4 raises the whole thing by 20 dB to coincide with curve 5 on the diagram.

Comment: how  do you know at 100 rad/sec you get 60 dB?

Comment: Curve 1 gets flattened by curve 2 at 100 rad/sec therefore it remains at 40 dB but curve 5 lifts it up by 20 dB.

Comment: where is the math? I understand the concept visually. how do you come up with these numbers?

Comment: If you didn't have curve 5 what would you see ?

Comment: 20 dB/decade is etched onto my soul. I've known it for so long that I don't need to prove it any more. Curve 1 rises at 20 dB/dec and curve 2 falls at 20 dB/dec - when both are applied together (100 rad/sec and above) a flat line results.